# Как подставить в SQL запрос данные из GET в php скрипте?

Tags: php, mysql

Вроде бы все должно работать, но что-то не идет :(

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
  mysql_select_db("topgame");
  $nicknm="$_GET["nickname"]"
  $scr=$_GET["score"]
  $eml="$_GET["email"]"
  $sql="INSERT INTO topgame(nickname, score, email) 
  values('$nicknm', '$scr', '$eml')";
  mysql_query("$sql");
?>
```

Сам get запрос выглядит так:
http://localhost/index2.php?nickname=ivanov&score=12345&email=ivanov@example.com

Comment: Что значит "но что-то не идет"?
Ошибки какие-то есть? Если есть, то как они проявляются?

Answer (score 5):

Ваш код подвержен SQL injection. [bobby-tables.com](http://www.bobby-tables.com/ru_RU/) читали? Подумайте, что будет если к вам в качестве email придёт строка `"lala@fafa.com'); DROP TABLE topgame;--"`?

Лучше пишите так:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=topgame;", "username", "password");
$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO topgame(nickname, score, email)
                         values(:nicknm, :scr, :eml)');

$sql->execute(array(':nicknm' => $nicknm, ':scr' => $scr, ':eml' => $eml));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за совет и поддержку, я просто всего пару часов потратил на то чтобы написать этот скрипт. К моему сожалению я просто еще не научился правильно читать код и поэтому не могу понять что для чего в вашем ответе.

Comment: @Артём Резниченко: смотрите. Значения, которые приходят в `$_GET`, _полностью_ контролируются клиентом. Даже если вы проверяете их джаваскриптом, клиент может отключить скрипты. Таким образом, значение переменной `$eml` может быть вообще произвольным. Есть?

Теперь представьте, что клиент злонамерен. Он может передать туда значение (например) `lala@fafa.com'); DROP TABLE topgame;--`. Что будет в этом случае в переменной `$sql`? А вот что:

    "INSERT INTO topgame(nickname, score, email) values('hax0r', '0', 'lala@fafa.com'); DROP TABLE topgame;--')"

Что будет, если вы выполните это?

Comment: @Артём Резниченко: А вот что: ваша таблица уничтожится. Видите?

Чтобы этого не произошло, надо сделать так, чтобы ввод пользователя интерпретировался не как часть команды, а как значение для вставки. То есть чтобы этот ввод не видел парсер. Для этого часто используется трюк с prepared statements, который и показан в ответе.

Comment: @Артём Резниченко: `$db->prepare` как бы создаёт команду с аргументами `:nicknm`, `:scr` и `:eml`. Потом команда `$sql->execute` выполняет эту команду, а значения аргументов передаются в массиве. Читайте тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Да,я уже сам разобрался ))) Я просто забыл ";" и знак кавычек для запроса SQL одинарный. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
 mysql_select_db("topgame");
  $nicknm = $_GET['nickname'];
   $scr = $_GET['score'];
   $eml = $_GET['email'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO topgame(nickname, score, email) VALUES('$nicknm', '$scr', '$eml')";
     mysql_query($sql);
     ?>
```